# Pass Core Data entity into custom overlay view

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking for help on how to pass a core data entity to a custom popover.

My list view:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)]) var entries: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    @State var entryPopOverVisible : Bool = false
    @State var currentEntry: Entry? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                if entries.count == 0 {
                    NoEntriesView()
                } else {
                    ForEach(entries) { entry in
                        Button {
                            withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 180, damping: 20).speed(0.95)) {
                                entryPopOverVisible.toggle()
                                currentEntry = entry
                            }
                        } label: {
                            ListCellView(entry: entry)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .overlay {
                if entryPopOverVisible {
                    PopOverBackground(
                        isPresented: $entryPopOverVisible
                    )
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .zIndex(0)
                    
                    EntryPopOver(
                        isPresented: $entryPopOverVisible,
                        entry: currentEntry
                    )
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))
                    .zIndex(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the popover:

```
struct EntryPopOver: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var entry: Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            popupCard
        }
    }
}

extension EntryPopOver {
    
    var popupCard: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            cardContent
            closeButton
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(.white)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24, style: .continuous))
        .padding()
    }
    
    var cardContent: some View {
        Text("\(entry.unwrappedLabel)")
    }
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 180, damping: 20).speed(0.95)) {
                isPresented = false
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Close")
        }
    }
}
```

On the `ListView` I'm getting the following error (the line above `.overlay`:

```
Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'
```

And on the `EntryPopOver` view, when I type `entry.` there's no autocomplete showing for the entity attributes which makes me think that view isn't correctly identifying the fact that the `Entry` entity is being passed to it. This approach was cobbled together from a few different sources online, so it's highly likely I'm missing something obvious.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change order

```
withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 180, damping: 20).speed(0.95)) {
  currentEntry = entry          // << here !!
  entryPopOverVisible.toggle()
}
```

however in such cases it is better to refer to only one optional state and use it, e.g.

```
@State private var selectedEntry: Entry?
```

Comment: I think that's improved things, but now I have an error saying `Value of optional type 'Entry?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Entry'` where I'm setting `currentEntry = entry`.

Comment: "I only show you a door" ;) ... it is your app.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help!